# При подключении компьютера Win 10 к домену Win Server 2008 R2 не открываются профили

Tags: windows, windows-10

Подключил компьютер Win 10 Pro к домену Win Server 2008 R2. И теперь не могу войти ни в один профиль домена. Под любым профилем он пишет:

> служба профилей не может выполнить вход

Под администратором домена он пытается войти до того момента, пока по времени не заблокируется. При разблокировке возможно вызвать диспетчер задач и всё. Не могли бы Вы помочь мне с этой проблемой?

Comment: И так, копирования в тупую папки с профилями с другого компьютера ничего не дало. Изменил немного групповую политику, убрал квоту, кастомные настройки оформления - эффекта не дало.

Comment: мало данных. У вас настроены перемещаемые профили? Шара, на которой они хранятся, доступна с проблемной машины? Создайте нового пользователя в домене с обычным, не перемещаемым профилем, без дополнительных настроек и политик и попробуйте на нем.

Comment: @rdom профили перемещаемые, в домене находятся компьютеры Win 7, раньше были Xp. Всё работало нормально. Здесь же такие проблемы начались с Win 10.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите скормить 10-тке профиль от 7-ки? Так не получится, они разные, в профиле 7-ки есть не все. При переходе с XP на 7 проблемы были те же, просто про них уже забыли. Создайте нового пользователя, для него профиль еще не создан, и залогиньтесь на этой машине, в процессе будет создан новый профиль. Посмотрите чем они отличаются, дальше по обстоятельствам. Попробуйте этим же пользователем зайти ни машине с 7-кой ни чего не меняя. Возможно придется обновлять профили. Вы же не храните документы пользователя в профиле?